# SSH ForceCommand example - require a user to enter a token before getting shell access?

Tags: ssh

I'd like to prompt a user for some piece of information *before* they get to their BASH shell when they're logging in via SSH. Ideally, I'd like to execute a script which prompts them for information, check that the information is correct, and then if it is drop them to a shell. So, think:

```
ssh user@some-host.com
password: xxxx

do you agree to the terms and conditions of use? enter yes or no:
yes 

OK, here's your shell:
#
```

Can anyone provide an example of how to do something like this?

Comment: This should be done in PAM, not via sshd.

Comment: OK, feel free to provide an example via PAM then too. Any particular reason why it should be done via PAM, and not SSHD?

Comment: For just a non-interactive banner, use can use the PAM config mentioned [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/149627/how-to-display-ssh-banner-at-login-but-only-for-password-authentication)

Comment: What about this? http://forum.yubico.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=860 It can also be done entirely in Perl. And, in case you want, there are PAM modules in perl, allowing it to be done in PAM.

Answer (score 1):

Create new login script(/bin/bash_rest):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "do you agree to the terms and conditions of use? enter yes or no:"
read ans

case $ans in
        y|yes|Y|Yes) bash;;
        *) exit
esac
```

and set as login shell:

```
chmod +x /bin/bash_rest
usermod -s /bin/bash_rest ooshro

ooshro@ooshro:~$ ssh -p 2022 localhost
Linux ubuntu-1010-server-01 2.6.35-25-generic-pae #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 21 19:01:46 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.10

Welcome to Ubuntu!
 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Thu Feb 24 17:43:06 2011 from 10.0.2.2
do you agree to the terms and conditions of use? enter yes or no:
yes
ooshro@ubuntu-1010-server-01:~$ exit
Connection to localhost closed.
ooshro@ooshro:~$ ssh -p 2022 localhost
Linux ubuntu-1010-server-01 2.6.35-25-generic-pae #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 21 19:01:46 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.10

Welcome to Ubuntu!
 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Thu Feb 24 17:43:17 2011 from 10.0.2.2
do you agree to the terms and conditions of use? enter yes or no:
no
Connection to localhost closed.
```

Comment: This can be overridden as peer can choose to connect and execute no/other shell.

Comment: ssh host "command" ; command can be any shell... if you want you can go as simple ash "sh"

Comment: ssh -p 2022 localhost  /bin/dash
do you agree to the terms and conditions of use? enter yes or no:

Comment: @Hrvoje Špoljar ssh host "command" don't work!..bring a example

Comment: Can anyone actually provide an example of how this is insecure/how a peer can override it?

Comment: Yes, the ssh manual provide an example of how to override it: `If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming for a moment that you're using opensshd, one possible alternative that does almost what you want, and is a lot simpler to implement, would be to use a login banner. This will not do exactly what you want it to do - it will display a text *before* the user logs in.

You can alter your policy accordingly - "by logging in you are accepting these terms and conditions".

You can do this using the "Banner" option in /etc/sshd/sshd_config. For example:

```
# echo "Banner /etc/sshd/sshd-banner" >> /etc/sshd/sshd_config
# echo "By logging on you're accepting the terms and conditions." > /etc/sshd/ssh-banner
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add some rudimentary logging to that bash script, and instead of making that script the default shell, I would consider /etc/ssh/sshrc or /etc/profile.local or /etc/profile. Testing is necessary, because behavior on different systems may vary. There are some reasons not to create non-standard shells, one of which is the need to add new shell to /etc/shells. Unless absolutely necessary, remain with shells defined in /etc/shells.